# How to get nodes between two nodes using xpath 1.0?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, html-agility-pack

There is the following html table. How to get all `tr` for "Session X" using xpath (Html agility pack)? (between `<tr><td colspan=15>Session X</td></tr>` and next Session `tr`)

There are two concerns,

1. Is it possible to relax a bit when comparing *Session X*? Because it may be

   ```
   Session X
   Session  X
   session_X
   ```
2. The next session text can be anything other than "Session X". Maybe it's better to check if the `<tr>` contains only one `<td colspan=15>`.

xml/html:

```
<table>
<tr><td colspan=15>Session A</td></tr>
.......
<tr><td colspan=15>Session X</td></tr>
<tr><td>...</td><td>Column header 1</td><td>value1</td><td>value2</td>......</tr>
<tr><td>...</td><td>Column header 2</td><td>value1</td>......</tr>
<tr><td>...</td><td>Column header 3</td><td>value1</td>......</tr>
.....
<tr><td colspan=15>Session Y</td></tr> <!--next session, the inner text can be anything-->
.....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you the `tr` with the info:

```
.//tr[preceding-sibling::tr/td/text()='Session X'][following-sibling::tr/td/text()='Session Y']
```

I don't think you sent enough information to know how to continue from there.

Comment: It's good enough to get `tr`. However, the following-sibling may not be exactly "Session Y". It can be any session name other than "Session X".

Comment: BTW, I got the error of `System.Xml.XPath.XPathException: Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function.` when trying the xpath.

Comment: There are mistakes in that path. It should be `following-sibling::` (note the two semicolons). As written, `preceding-sibling:tr` and `following-sibling:tr` appear to be namespace prefixes, not XPath axes.

Comment: Fixed, thanks. I’m lacking xslt on my iPad and hadn’t checked if I made a stupid mistake or there was some C# special problems. I should have, sorry for that …